# Constructing Mesh In FreeFem++

Tags: mesh, freefem++

I am new to building 3D meshes in FreeFem. Is it possible to build the mesh below? The domain is 1+1/8 in length, 1 height, and 1 width. There is a 1/4 depth and 1/8 wide channel that cuts though it at a 45 degree angle. (Schematic attached)

[image: Schematic]

I have been able to construct a similar domain using buildlayers command with the channel orthogonal to the edge but now that it is slanted I have no idea how to generate it.

-Fluidman